# Keycloak with external IDP

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-connect

I am using keycloak (version 8.0.1) as an identity broker in my application(app1).  In my application user can sign using external idp(google, fb) or from our login page.  For now, I setup another Keycloak instance and configured it as IDP using OIDC.  It works fine.

If the user is allready signed into external idp(google, fb) and click on my app(app1) from app2's webpage.  Is there a way, can I automatically let the user in, rather than redirecting him to my app(app1) login page.

Comment: Were you able to achieve this ?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do that by setting kc_idp_hint parameter
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#default_identity_provider